# jQuery - Get a custom ajax option set by ajaxSetup in ajaxStart or ajaxSend

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm going to set a custom variable in `ajaxSetup` as below:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    spinner: true
});
```

So be able to set spinner `true` or `flase` for each separate ajax request and check it in `ajaxSend` event.

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, options) {
    if(options.spinner) $("#spinner").show();
})
```

Is there a way to do that?

**EDIT**

Surprisingly it's working just after I posted the question. It wasn't working before that and `spinner` was always true. I don't close the question because maybe someone else has the same issue.

Comment: are you sure you can set **custom options** in `ajaxSetup`?

Comment: this should work...what is the issue?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yes, I have set ;)

Comment: @Jai Surprisingly it's working just after I posted the question. It wasn't working after that and  `spinner` was always true.

Comment: @Omid you can post the answer that why it started working otherwise this post is not good for others because there is no solution any one provided.

Answer (score 0):

Without the extra option you can use:

```
$(".loadeContainer").ajaxStart(function () 
{
    $(this).show();
}).ajaxStop(function ()
 {
    $(this).hide();
});
```